# Starting cron job to run Flask app in venv on Beagle Bone

Tags: python, flask, cron, beagleboard

I have a simple Flask app (called `io_server`) within a virtualenv. This directory structure looks like this:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/debian/io_server
```

I want to automatically start the Flask app on reboot of the Beagle Bone.

To do this I created a crontab with the following line:

```
@reboot cd /home/debian/io_server && . venv/bin/activate && flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

It doesn't work.

Is there an obvious problem with the command in the crontab? otherwise is there a way to inspect the output of the attempted execution of this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought exporting the `FLASK_APP` environment variable was a permanent export. Apparently not.

Changing the command to:

```
@reboot cd /home/debian/io_server && . venv/bin/activate && export FLASK_APP=io_server.py && flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

has solved the problem.